# How do I store a variable of type `impl Trait` in a struct?

Tags: rust, future

This works:

```
let fut = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::pin(async { 1 })));

let mut conn_futures = BTreeMap::new(); // implicitly typed
conn_futures.insert(123, fut);
if let Some(fut) = conn_futures.get_mut(&123) {
   let fut = fut.clone();
   self.pool.spawn(async move {
        let mut fut = fut.try_lock().unwrap();
        (&mut *fut).await;
    });
};
```

How do I write the same thing inside a structure; what is the type of `conn_futures`? According to the compiler, it's `BTreeMap<i32, impl Future>`, but there's no way to write that in a structure:

```
struct Foo {
    conn_futures: BTreeMap<i32, impl Future>, // impl not allow in this position
}
```

I tried this:

```
use futures::{executor::LocalPool, lock::Mutex, task::SpawnExt, Future}; // 0.3.1
use std::{collections::BTreeMap, pin::Pin, sync::Arc};

struct Foo {
    conn_futures: BTreeMap<i32, Arc<Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = i32>>>>>>,
}

fn alternative() {
    let mut pool = LocalPool::new();
    let spawner = pool.spawner();

    // Have a structure with the btreemap instead
    let mut foo = Foo {
        conn_futures: BTreeMap::new(),
    };
    let fut = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::pin(async { 1 })));
    foo.conn_futures.insert(123, fut);
    if let Some(fut) = foo.conn_futures.get_mut(&123) {
        let fut = fut.clone();
        spawner.spawn(async move {
            let mut fut = fut.try_lock().unwrap();
            (&mut *fut).await;
        });
    };
}

fn main() {
    let mut pool = LocalPool::new();
    let spawner = pool.spawner();
    let fut = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::pin(async { 1 })));

    let mut conn_futures = BTreeMap::new(); // implicitly typed
    conn_futures.insert(123, fut);
    if let Some(fut) = conn_futures.get_mut(&123) {
        let fut = fut.clone();
        spawner.spawn(async move {
            let mut fut = fut.try_lock().unwrap();
            (&mut *fut).await;
        });
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb30cc4e1d90af5b2f3cb78d7ce4e71e)

And got an error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:34
   |
17 |     foo.conn_futures.insert(123, fut);
   |                                  ^^^ expected trait core::future::future::Future, found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected type `std::sync::Arc<futures_util::lock::mutex::Mutex<std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)>>>>`
              found type `std::sync::Arc<futures_util::lock::mutex::Mutex<std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<impl core::future::future::Future>>>>`
```

How do I declare the type of `conn_futures` in a struct?

Comment: `impl` just means "any type that implements this trait". To store it in a struct or enum, you have 3 options: 1) make the stuct generic, e.g. `struct Foo<T: Future>`, 2) use the concrete type that implements the trait, 3) use a trait object, e.g. `Box<dyn Future>`

Comment: In this example (2) or (3) don't seem to work. Did you manage to get it to work on the playground? And 1 would leak out details of an internal implementation to the outside world

Comment: For `Future` option (2) doesn't work if the future is from an async block. But option (3) works. Just cast the result of `Box::pin` to `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = i32>>>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot, really. `impl Trait` creates an anonymous, unnameable type. That means that you cannot declare a variable with an explicit type that will work.

The primary solution is to use a *trait object*:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn make_it() -> impl Display {
    2
}

struct Example {
    it: Box<dyn Display>,
}

impl Example {
    fn make() -> Self {
        Example {
            it: Box::new(make_it()),
        }
    }
}
```

You can also avoid using an associated function and use a plain function instead, coupled with a generic:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn make_it() -> impl Display {
    2
}

struct Example<T> {
    it: T,
}

impl Example<Box<dyn Display>> {
    fn make() -> Self {
        Example {
            it: Box::new(make_it()),
        }
    }
}

fn make_example() -> Example<impl Display> {
    Example {
        it: make_it(),
    }
}
```

#### Nightly only

If you wish to use unstable nightly features, you can use [*existential types* (RFC 2071)](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2071-impl-trait-existential-types.html):

```
// 1.51.0-nightly (2021-01-03 80184183ba0a53aa4f49)
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

use std::fmt::Display;

type SomeDisplay = impl Display;

fn make_it() -> SomeDisplay {
    2
}

struct Example {
    it: SomeDisplay,
}

impl Example {
    fn make() -> Self {
        Example { it: make_it() }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
// 1.51.0-nightly (2021-01-03 80184183ba0a53aa4f49)
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

use std::fmt::Display;

fn make_it() -> impl Display {
    2
}

struct Example<T> {
    it: T,
}

type SomeDisplay = impl Display;

impl Example<SomeDisplay> {
    fn make() -> Self {
        Example { it: make_it() }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)
- [Why can impl trait not be used to return multiple / conditional types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52001592/155423)
- [Is it possible to use `impl Trait` as a function's return type in a trait definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39482131/155423)
- [What makes something a "trait object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27567849/155423)
- [What is the advantage of publishing a concrete type in a crate's API instead of `impl trait`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52079983/155423)

Answer (score -1):

Though the suggestions above are useful, the specific answer to the question is to cast the `Pin<Box<Future>>>` appropriately

This line

```
let fut = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::pin(async { 1 })));
```

needs to change

```
let fut = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::pin(async { 1 }) as Pin<Box<Future<Output=i32>>> ));
```

which will allow one to express the following struct

```
struct Foo {
    conn_futures: BTreeMap<ChannelId, Arc<Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = i32>>>>>>,
}
```

and the compiler won't complain. Thanks @Aloso for the hint

However, the following error is given instead

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:24:16
   |
24 |        spawner.spawn(async move {
   |                ^^^^^ `(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::ptr::Unique<(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `futures_util::lock::mutex::Mutex<std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)>>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<futures_util::lock::mutex::Mutex<std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)>>>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/main.rs:24:33: 27:10 fut:std::sync::Arc<futures_util::lock::mutex::Mutex<std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)>>>> _]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:24:33: 27:10 fut:std::sync::Arc<futures_util::lock::mutex::Mutex<std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'static)>>>> _]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
```

which will be a separate question

Comment: Please pay attention to the compiler warnings about this code and adjust it accordingly.